# Export runnable JAR in Eclipse with only imported classes

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have an Eclipse project containing classes and interfaces that I use in other projects. This codebase has grown quite large over the years. The problem I have is when I export a project to a runnable JAR, Eclipse will copy every class file from my codebase, even if I only import one simple class from it.

Example: my codebase consists of the class files `codebase/Car.class`, `codebase/House.class` and `codebase/Garage.class`. In a separate project, I have the source file `project/App.java`, looking like this:

```java
import codebase.Car;
import codebase.House;

public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Car car = new Car();
        House house = new House();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to export my project with only `project/App.class`, `codebase/Car.class` and `codebase/House.class` (but not with `codebase/Garage.class`, since it's not used), or do I have to write a custom build script?

Comment: as far as I know it's not work for eclipse, it's the jar packaging system, and it does not have dependency checking, even using maven only provides a package level dependency.

Comment: This is by design.  This is to get the same environment as inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main project is built with maven, you can use the [Apache maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) and especially the minimize-feature to do the job. I'm using it for years now and it always did a good job. It will build one big jar containing all really used classes and it will not only evict classes from your own jars but also from the deployed standard libs.